# How was the conflict between Henry II of England and Thomas Becket affected by the Concordat of Worms?

Tags: england

In my limited reading about Henry II of England and his conflict with Thomas Becket, I don't remember learning about Holy Roman Emperor Henry V.

Is there any evidence that Henry II of England or Thomas Becket mentioned, thought about and/or referenced the [Concordat of Worms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concordat_of_Worms) (or the preceding conflicts)?

Comment: Don't you mean [Henry II of England](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_II_of_England)?

Comment: Given that the conflict was "This led to a series of conflicts with the King, including that over the jurisdiction of secular courts over English clergymen, which accelerated antipathy between Becket and the king. " [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Becket)There is no reason why the Holy Roman Emperor would have been involved.

Comment: The concordat of worms is 1122; Becket is 1170. Worms governs investiture; the [Constitutions of Clarendon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constitutions_of_Clarendon) concern the venue for trying a cleric accused of a crime.

Comment: I re-worded the question.  I understand which came first but my original draft of the question wasn't clear.

Comment: Much clearer; I still think the issues were disjoint - Becket was about the power of the English crown to manage English affairs. Worms was more about investiture.   I may try to answer later, but this is on the outside edge of my competence.  Interesting question.

Comment: It seems to me the specifics were different but both were clearly the result of the natural friction between church and state.